# Jquery thick box is not coming in IE

Tags: jquery, thickbox

i have  jquery thick box, and it is loading on clicking some link.

Then if i click an radio button on the thick box form, it will close the thick box form  and another thick box form will open.

But the second thick box is not coming in IE.
Its working in Mozilla

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">


/* Display the search popup according to the radio button selection **/
function show_search (value)
{

    tb_remove();
    var url= 'url1'; 


    setTimeout("tb_show('Change Details','"+url+"');",1*500);
    return false;
}

 </script>

<form class="jNice" action="" method="post" onsubmit="javascript:return formCarSrch_validate(this);" id="hotel_search_popup">

                <h2>Search Hotels</h2>
                 <input name="category"  type="radio" value="F"  class="radioSearch"  onclick="return show_search(this.value);"/><label>Flight</label>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the documentation in the following link:

[JQuery Thick box][1]

**[1]: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/**

And use the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="thickbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function show_search (value)
  { 
   var url= 'http://www.google.com'; 
   tb_show('Change Details','"+url+"');   
   setTimeout("remove()",1*100);
   return false;
  }
  function remove()
  { 
    tb_remove();    
    alert("check");
   } 
 </script> 
</head> 
<body>
<form id="hotel_search_popup">
<h2>Search Hotels</h2>
<input name="category"  type="radio" value="F"  class="radioSearch"  onclick="return show_search(this.value);"/>
<label>Flight</label>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```